# SSIS Incremental Load for many various tables and schemas

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis, ssms, etl

I'm an intermediate database programmer and have been using SSIS for a couple years now, and feel like I have a pretty basic understanding, and I've always used the Incremental Load structure shown by [Andy Leonard here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/). My problem is I've never had to deal with more than about 15 files at a time for this proecss.

I now have a new project, which requires incremental loading for 200 text files, range in size anywhere from 500MB to 2GB, and columns ranging from 3 to 232 columns.

I understand I can't loop through these files with a ForEach container, because of the different schemas, but is there really no other option than to have 200 different connection managers and 200 seperate tasks?

I have a working bcp to import them into SSMS and my best idea thus far is to leave all fields as text at import, then maybe I could create ForEach containers for all tables with the same number of columns? My thought process being metadata is technically the same (all varchar columns, same number of columns), and I could do my transformations on the final tables after the incremental loads have taken place. This would at least cut the process down to one connection manager, and about 100 variables and 100 tasks as there are only 100 different combination of columns(if that makes sense.)

Any advice, thoughs or links to similar solutions would be fantastic.

Thank you.

Comment: You may be able to do this with sp_executesql with openquery with the commands coming from a file. I don't see how you can do this in SSIS. It expects to have a separate data flow task for each source and target.

Comment: Maybe you could look into writing a really flexible script task that will loop through files, analyze their contents, and incrementally load them.

Comment: Andy's a smart guy and there's no way he'd manually create those packages. Instead, he's going to reach for a tool to automate that Incremental load pattern. If you look at it, what's different in each package? The source definition, the guts of the lookup and the target table(s). The basic patten holds true - identify new data, test, save and count everywhere. Whether you reach for the base SSIS API, or EzAPI or something different like Biml & BimlScript, maybe TaskFactory is up to you. I'm infatuated with the expressiveness of Biml (feel free to look through my answers for past few months)

Comment: Are any of those BCP imports complex enough that they require format files or are you just doing straight BCP?

Comment: @BradD the BCP as of now is just strictly bcp at this point, no transformations. I had originally planned to do those in SSIS.

Comment: @billinkc I spent the night trying out Biml, and I think this is a great solution! The only problem is I'm in a larger company, whose IT is outsourced to a third party. I don't even have permissions to turn on the volume to my pc. So I will have to start working up the ranks to request permissions to use this.

Comment: The BIDS Helper people heard about situations like that and there's a no-install version. If you can download the zip file, you extract it to `MyDocuments\Visual Studio ####\Addins` That's in your MyDocuments folder so you ought to have permissions there. Works like a charm and no one will be any the wiser that you built your packages through a tool instead of by hand

Comment: Can't initiate downloads on this machine either, but I can certainly try to download the file on another machine, and try to transfer to myDocs via flash drive. I'll try sometime this weekend and let you know. @billinkc

Answer (score 0):

The [workaround](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=xcopy%20deploy&referringTitle=Documentation) to extract the Bids Helper in MyDocuments and adding to Visual Studio work and pretty easy. Make sure and manually add in the schema as well.

I've now written a few biml scripts in order to accomplish this task. The first was to use a loop to create a dtsx package for each table, using the LookUp and ConditionalSplit tasks to accomplish the Incremental Load. This works great for small to medium sized tables, but for the larger tables, millions of rows and hundreds of columns, its extremely slow as the LookUp has to cache the data into memory, if you even have enough memory to accomplish this! More about [calculating LookUp cache size here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/10/18/calculating-the-size-of-your-lookup-cache.aspx).

My solution for this, was to write a seperate biml script to create a package for each table that will execute a merge statement with the Execute Sql Task. This seems the best way as Merge is much more efficient than lookup.

The third biml script was to generate a package that will then run all the other packages.

Another benefit to using biml is that if there are any changes to the tables, schemas etc, all you need to do is rerun the biml script and it will rebuild all the dtsx packages for you.

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: Can you provide your biml scripts as I am a newbie and need to implement such scenario.